# Amazon EC2 IP at the Prompt

Tags: amazon-ec2

when I log into my instance there is a certain IP address that refers to it.  However, once I login I see some thing like:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$
```

Why is the xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ip different than the IP used to login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 instances have [both an internal and an external IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html). While you access it over the public internet via the external IP, the instance internally knows itself as its private, internal IP address.